# Cloud flare 301 partially working

Tags: cloudflare

I have `.htaccess 301` redirect for cloud flare but it redirects the main page but not other pages.  ex. when you domain.com it redirects to https://domain.com but when you open `domain.com/new-page-html`, then it does not redirect to https:

Below is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off doing a redirect in CloudFlare as a "Page Rule". That way your traffic is redirected before it arrives your server. They have a special rule for you to do http -> https redirection.

See: [How do I redirect all visitors to HTTPS/SSL?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-) on CloudFlare

Update:

CloudFlare has a "Always use HTTPS" switch now. You can setup for http://domain.com/* and flip on the switch and that's it!

[image]

Comment: My domain has thousands of url which is not possible to set page rule for every link. when you set rules for domain.com  it only redirects domain.com but NOT domain.com/new-page-html  Thank you

Comment: you can use wild card. see the help doc i mentioned.

Comment: @Hsb i have a rule that will redirect http://domain.com/* to https://domain.com/$1 this will make all of the http redirected to https for domain.com

Comment: Can you please paste the rule here. Thanks for your time

Comment: all you need is here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-

Comment: Hi william.  Did you actully understand what I mean.  I do not want to redirect domain.com to domain.com/$1   What I want is all the url should be redirected to https:// . Currently htacess and page rule only redirect one url not all.

Comment: @Hsb FYI there is 2 ways to do it in CloudFlare. One way is just toggle the "always use HTTPS" switch for http://domain.com/*. The other way is using forwarding http://domain/* to https://domain/$1. $1 is NOT just a url, it will take whatever you have in your * wildcard and put it there. So for the http://domain/* -> https://domain/$1 rule. It will forward http://domain/whatever to https://domain/whatever . It's all in the CloudFlare guide if you just read it!

Comment: @Hsb you need domain/* without the * it will not redirect anything but http://domain

Comment: Thank you very much william for your time.  I found the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think I have found the solution.  Go to cloudflare > page rules

Just add domain.com/*   (with slash and star)  and then turn on use " http always "

It will redirect all the URls

domain.com/1.html
domain.com/etc

Special thanks to william who helped me finding the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than an .htaccess 301 you should probably create the following CloudFlare Page Rule:

1. If the URL matches - http://*domain.com*
2. CLICK "+ A Setting" and select "Always Use HTTPS"
3. Make sure the ORDER is set to FIRST (optional but recommended)
4. CLICK Save and Deploy

You can find some helpful video tutorials for this and other popular rules at:

https://www.cloudflare.com/features-page-rules/

Comment: Although your answer might be correct providing **JUST** a link in your answer isn't very helpful. If the link were ever to go offline your answer becomes useless and invalid. Links are meant to help improve your answer not meant to be a replacement for providing quality answers in the body itself.